# How to set the data context for a combobox in View from the ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, mvvm

I have a DataTable called Courses={courseID,courseName,SNTeacher,education}.I would like to bind the column "education" to the combobox in my view and so I have made a method in my RegisterTeacherViewModel that will select all the values from the "Courses"table,"education" column and display them in the combobox.This is my method:

```
   public void GetByEducation()
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(my conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string query = "SELECT education FROM Courses ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
               education= dr.GetString(1);

            }


        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Everything is ok,but in the view when I want to establish the datacontext for the combobox,it says"Cannot implicitly convert type "void" to System.Collection.IEnumerable" although I don't have an ObservableCollection for education.This is my Register.xaml.cs class:

```
   public partial class Register : Window
  {
    RegisterTeacherViewModel regTeacher;
    public Register()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        regTeacher = new RegisterTeacherViewModel();
        this.DataContext = regTeacher;
        cbxCourses.ItemsSource = regTeacher.GetByEducation();//this is where the error occurs.

    }


    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Your method returns void. Please change the return type to your Teacher or whatever is the name of the class which has that method. You will have to return an IEnumerable. public IEnumerable<your-type> GetByEducation()

Comment: It worked!Thank you!I tried to do it as you said but I got an error the first time.Now is OK.If you want,you can make your comm an answer so that I can mark it as correct.:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change method GetByEducation() return type void to a collection.

```
public List<Courses> GetByEducation()
{
    List<Courses> education = new List<Courses>();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(my conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query = "SELECT education FROM Courses ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
           education= dr.GetString(1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    return education;
}
```